# Filtering Association By Another Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a friendship model that contains a status.

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :friend_id, :user_id, :source_id

  after_create :check_friend_status

  # Relationships
  belongs_to :user, :touch => true
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User", :touch => true
  belongs_to :source

  has_one :status, :class_name => "FriendStatusDescriptor", :foreign_key => 'friendship_id'


  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => [:friend_id, :source_id]


  def check_friend_status
    # Check user/friend for existing friend status
    if FriendStatusDescriptor.find(:first, :conditions => ["friendship_id = ?", self.id]).nil?
        status = FriendStatusDescriptor.new
        status.friendship_id = self.id
        status.save
    end
  end
end

class FriendStatusDescriptor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :alert, :friendship_id, :hide

  belongs_to :friendship

  validates_uniqueness_of :friendship_id

end
```

The status model has a boolean variable called hide.  I want to be able to filter my user's friendships by the ones with hide set to false.  Something along these lines.

```
      #  In User Model
  # Friendships
  has_many :friendships do
    def visible
         #  Where !friendship.status.hide
    end
  end
```

So that in my controller I can just do this

```
 user.friendships.visible
```

I'm not sure how to access the individual friendship in this method though.

Comment: Try this: `user.friendships.joins(:status).where(status: { hide: false })`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
class User
  has_many :friendships,
    :class_name => "FriendStatusDescriptor",
    :foreign_key => 'friendship_id'
```

If you want to filter visible and non-visible friendships by separete you can add scopes to Friendship model:

```
class Friendship
  scope :visible, -> { joins(:status).where("friend_status_descriptors.hide = ?", false) }
```

Then apply that scope:

```
user.friendships.visible
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.   It would be where :status.hide => false  But I get this error NoMethodError (undefined method `hide' for :status:Symbol):

Comment: That's because you are trying to call a method `status` on a symbol, which is mostly just a string. I'm assuming 'hide' is a boolean field on your friendships table, isn't it?

Comment: hide is a boolean field in the FriendStatusDescriptor. I've edited the question with full classes.

Comment: :class_name is the class, i.e. the table, form where you want to take the records. So if you want Friendships, start by specifying class_name: Friendships there

Comment: The scope is what I'm looking for, but since hide isn't in the friendship model I get an error.  Why can't I access it through the :status relationship?

Comment: I have getting friendships working.  The association is ok.  The only issue I'm having is with filtering on a field in the associated object's association.  So essentially what I need is `scope :visible,    ->{ where status.hide: false }`  But that crashes because it doesn't know what status is.

Comment: I think I got a clue. Check sope [ActiveRecord scopes docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope). See my edit.

Comment: It thinks I'm trying to access hide on the friendship model Error: Unknown column 'friendships.hide' in 'where clause'

Comment: however if I use sql `scope :visible, -> { joins(:status).where("friend_status_descriptors.hide = ?", false) }` seems to be good to go.

Comment: If you want to update your answer with this scope stuff, I'll accept it.  Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Congrats! That last "bug" may have to do with ActiveRecord version.